# How to iterate and get the json values using angularjs ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to iterate and get the name values: `test01`, `test02` and `test03` on my ng-repeat for my given json. How can I get it using ng-repeat ? Please let me know and thanks in advance.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/jfj1ctnm/) is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.Test">
  <td> {{value.Testing.static.name}} </td>
</tr>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nh5zxoka/3/

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
 "Test": [{
  "Testing": {
   "static": {
    "name": "test01"
   },
   "testboolean": true
  }
 }, {
  "Testing": {
   "static": {
    "name": "test02"
   },
   "secondstatic": "yes"
  }
 }, {
  "Testing": {
   "static": {
    "name": "test03"
   }
  }
 }]
};

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="d in data.Test">
      <td> {{d.Testing.static.name}} </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem, Glad to see that it helped you :) @Dhana

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the (key, value) here, just

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <table>
   <tr ng-repeat="val in data.Test">
      <td> {{val.Testing.static.name}} </td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

key[0] - is just the first letter of the key "Test"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do the trick:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table>
     <tr ng-repeat="value in data.Test">
        <td> {{value.Testing.static.name}} </td> 
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you are sure that the hierarchy of your JSON will remain the same, then there is no need to iterate in the json properties by using `(key, value) in data`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0gucxcq2/).

Comment: thank you for your help and it's working fine as expected !

Comment: np, glad it helped